# Drag emails from OWA Web Part to a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, outlook

Is it possible to drag/send an email from the OWA Webpart in a Sharepoint site to a list or a custom page on the site? i.e. Can the webpart be customized?

The business case is the filing of emails and their attachments. I'd like to give users the ability to do this from within their sharepoint site instead of going to outlook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the particular use-case you are asking, but I know with SharePoint 2013 you can have "[site mailboxes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/add-a-site-mailbox-to-keep-email-in-context-HA103863011.aspx)" and perform exactly what you are asking with it. You can drag directly from mailbox into a folder in your outlook, which would be associated with a mailbox on your SharePoint site. A great way to keep project-related emails synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this is a problem. There's a max of 10 site mailboxes in Outlook, and the users will need a lot more than that. Also, I want the emails themselves stored in Sharepoint.